# How to query plan only a specific query in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure which is contains a lot of query.

I Would like to execute the query plan only for a specific query.

EX:

```
select * from A

select * from B
--QUERY PLAN THIS
select * from C
--END OF QUERY PLAN

select * from D
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: do you know how to copy and paste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really can't do that.  So you have to work around the problem by extracting that specific bit of SQL and building its execution plan by itself.

It may be that you're curious to see if the execution plan is affected when running in the context of the rest of the stored procedure.  In that case you'll have to go ahead and generate a plan on the whole procedure and decipher what piece of it is the query you're concerned with.

You may also find SQL profiler helpful when trying to optimize/troubleshoot specific elements of complicated procedures.